# Glass submarines, sea serpents and aliens at the bottom of a deep sea trench

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to identify a book I read at school back in the early 1980s. It featured small glass submarines, elusive sea serpents, and once the sea serpents were tracked down, aliens hiding under a force field at the bottom of a deep sea trench.

Unfortunately the school library burned down the following year so I was never able to return to this book.

It is not *The Deep Range* by Arthur C. Clarke, but the unknown book does seem to follow up on loose threads from *The Deep Range*, so maybe there was a sequel.

Comment: Novelization of *The Abyss*?

Comment: @Paulie_D 1989 is a bit late though...

Comment: After 20+ years memories are fallible ☺

Comment: Attack from Atlantis, 1953, by Lester Del Ray? This novel has no sea serpents, but does have ichthyosaurs; no small glass subs, but has Atlanteans swimming inside form-fitting force field bubbles; and does have the Atlanteans living under a force field at the bottom of the Milwaukee Deep.

Comment: @StanleyWebb.  Attack from Atlantis was my first thought as well.

Comment: @StanleyWebb. Looks like an interesting story, but without the sea serpents and glass submarines it's only ticking one box - the force field in a trench.